# Animate element position in received one via web sockets using JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, web, animation, websocket

The feature is to draw the cars moving by track. Track shape is simplified to circle. I receive the data via web sockets ~5 frames per second. In every frame I receive the pecentage driven by track per moment for every car and depending on this value I move the car on the circle.

It works well, but movement looks 'sharply' and I need to smooth the movement as if it is a real car moving. I will be grateful for any suggestion or advice[This is the track circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qIoS.png)

Comment: We can't really give you any suggestions without looking at your code. Please edit your question to make a [mre].

Comment: Please add more details to the question as code. It will be helpful when answering the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.